# Question on Borel-measurable maps on topological groups

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, topological-groups

On page 341 of Follad's Real Analysis 2nd edition, it is written that "it is easy to see that every Borel measurable function on G is constant on the cosets of H" where $G$ is a topological group and $H$ is the closure of $\{e\}$ where $e$ the identity element of $G$.

With the understanding that by a "Borel-measurable map" we mean a complex or real-valued function defined on $G$, I can see that the statement is true for all continuous functions, but I'm not sure why this must be true for all Borel-measurable maps.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Isn't $\overline{\{e\}}$ indiscrete? Every open subset in $\overline{\{e\}}$ has to contain $e$ (by definition of closure and subspace topology). And then since $\overline{\{e\}}$ is homogenous (as every topological group is) then every open subset has to contain every element. Hence $\overline{\{e\}}$ is indiscrete, and therefore the Borel $\sigma$-algebra is indiscrete as well. Which means that every measurable map to reals or complex has to be constant. Did I make a mistake here? I post it as a comment, because it sounds slightly too strong...